Downloading attachments from TRELLO API 401
When downloading images I get a 401 error. I receive data about card attachments through the API. I receive the data successfully. but I can’t download, if I transfer the token and API key I still get 401
import os

# URL карточки Trello, откуда берется вложение
url = "https://api.trello.com/1/cards/{id}/attachments"

# Заголовки запроса
headers = {
    "Accept": "application/json"
}

# Параметры запроса с ключом и токеном
query = {
    'key': '',
    'token': ''
}

# Отправка запроса на получение вложений
response = requests.get(url, headers=headers, params=query)

# Проверка успешности запроса
if response.status_code == 200:
    # Разбор JSON-ответа
    attachments = response.json()
    
    # Перебор всех вложений
    for attachment in attachments:
        # Получаем URL изображения
        image_url = attachment.get('url')
        
        if image_url:
            print(f"Загружаем изображение с URL: {image_url}")
            # Получаем имя файла из URL
            image_name = image_url.split('/')[-1]

            # Путь к рабочему столу
            desktop_path = os.path.join(os.path.expanduser("~"), "Desktop", image_name)

            # Загрузка изображения
            image_response = requests.get(image_url, stream=True)
            
            if image_response.status_code == 200:
                # Сохранение изображения на рабочем столе
                with open(desktop_path, 'wb') as f:
                    for chunk in image_response.iter_content(1024):
                        f.write(chunk)
                print(f"Изображение сохранено: {desktop_path}")
            else:
                print(f"Ошибка при загрузке изображения: {image_response.status_code}")
        else:
            print("Не найден URL для вложения.")
else:
    print(f"Ошибка при получении вложений: {response.status_code}")

I hid confidential data
